# Как расположить поиск по товарам Woocomerce под заголовком?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Добрый день. Я новичок в Wordpress. Подскажите пожалуйста, как перенести поиск по товарам из виджета под заголовок страницы?

Изображение прилагается.

[image: Приложение к вопросу]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возьмите файл `/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php` и скопируйте его в папку `/wp-content/themes/Divi/woocommerce/archive-product.php`. Это сохранит ваши изменения при обновлении WooCommerce. Но для того, чтобы обновлять потом саму тему Divi, надо создать дочернюю тему. Подробно об этом можно прочитать [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/id_6235/dochernie-temy-wordpress.html).

В стандартной поставке Divi такого файла нет. Если все же он создан разработчиками сайта, то его нужно отредактировать.

В районе 40 строки файла `archive-product.php` после строк

```
    <?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_show_page_title', true ) ) : ?>

        <h1 class="page-title"><?php woocommerce_page_title(); ?></h1>

    <?php endif; ?>
```

вставьте строку

```
    <?php get_product_search_form(); ?>
```

Строка обеспечивает вывод формы поиска WooCommerсe после заголовка страницы.

В админке на странице "Внешний вид->Виджеты" найдите сайдбар WooCommerce и удалите из него верхний виджет - виджет поиска.

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, как найти это нужное место? В этом и вопрос.

Comment: А на этот вопрос непонятно как ответить. У вас страница может быть сформирована 10 разными способами. Это вообще что на картинке - отображение страницы или категории товаров?

Comment: Укажите какая тема используется, с какой страницы делаете скриншот. Без подробной информации вам не смогут помочь

Comment: Эта страница категорий товаров, вот ссылка на сайт kartina-color.ru . Мне нужно понять как сделать чтоб поиск располагался сразу надо товарами / категорями

Comment: Расширил ответ.